# Oracle merge into delete from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the delete statement in the last. Essentially , I want to delete only if merge returned rows or matched. Is it possible to do in one single `merge into` statement ?

```
MERGE INTO ${TABLE_NAME} T
USING (
    SELECT
    ERRORCODE, PROCESSINGFILENAME,
    RECORDNUMBER from ERROR_UPLOAD_T
 ) TMP
ON (T.RECORDNUMBER = TMP.RECORDNUMBER and
T.PROCESSINGFILENAME= TMP.PROCESSINGFILENAME and
T.PROCESSINGFILENAME='${new_err_xml}')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
    T.STATUS = 'ERROR',
    T.ERRORSOURCE = 'BRM',
    T.ERRORCODE = TMP.ERRORCODE

DELETE from ERROR_UPLOAD_T WHERE
PROCESSINGFILENAME like '${new_err_xml}';
```

If not possible this way, please tell me better way to do this. This particular statement is called in shell script using sqlplus.

EDIT: I tried this way and it looks to working.

BEGIN

```
MERGE INTO ${TABLE_NAME} T
USING (
    SELECT
    ERRORCODE, PROCESSINGFILENAME,
    RECORDNUMBER from ERROR_UPLOAD_T
 ) TMP
ON (T.RECORDNUMBER = TMP.RECORDNUMBER and
T.PROCESSINGFILENAME= TMP.PROCESSINGFILENAME and
T.PROCESSINGFILENAME='${new_err_xml}')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
    T.STATUS = 'ERROR',
    T.ERRORSOURCE = 'BRM',
    T.ERRORCODE = TMP.ERRORCODE;

if (sql%rowcount > 0) then
    DELETE from ERROR_UPLOAD_T WHERE
    PROCESSINGFILENAME like '${new_err_xml}';
end if;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you managed to answer your own question then you're encouraged to actually post it as an answer, not an edit.

Comment: And no, you can't delete from the source table (from the `using` clause) as part of the merge statement.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I didn't know I can answer my own post. But my question still remains same `can we achieve in single merge into condition`. I posted my answer below.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks ! I was waiting for your answer as most of my sql post you have helped. So does the solution i figure out is good enough? any better way?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Correct, but you can delete from the target table.  SQL queries that modify data can only modify data on one table at a time.

Comment: @Mr.Llama - apart from `insert all`, if you count that as 'modify' *8-) But yes, I was talking about the source, and expanded a little in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve the result by changing the query in following manner.

```
BEGIN
MERGE INTO ${TABLE_NAME} T
USING (
    SELECT
    ERRORCODE, PROCESSINGFILENAME,
    RECORDNUMBER from ERROR_UPLOAD_T
 ) TMP
ON (T.RECORDNUMBER = TMP.RECORDNUMBER and
T.PROCESSINGFILENAME= TMP.PROCESSINGFILENAME and
T.PROCESSINGFILENAME='${new_err_xml}')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
    T.STATUS = 'ERROR',
    T.ERRORSOURCE = 'BRM',
    T.ERRORCODE = TMP.ERRORCODE;

if (sql%rowcount > 0) then
    DELETE from ERROR_UPLOAD_T WHERE
    PROCESSINGFILENAME like '${new_err_xml}';
end if;

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: This seems slightly odd. If *any* rows in source match any in the target - so you do at least one update - then you delete all rows in the source; not just those that actually matched. And if no rows match then you keep tham all. I don't immediately see how that is useful, unless you're expecting to add matching rows to the destination table and run it again later. But that then goes back to the 'any' part. It just seems odd - if that is what you really want then this is how to check.

Comment: @AlexPoole you are right, there parallel processing running that can create a error rows with details. So i will keep them until they are loaded. But yes, if they fail to load then, it is manual to reprocess them and load. Finally, Source and destination must match at one point, so I believe it will be deleted when matched.

Comment: @AlexPoole Problem with my earlier statement is , it is getting deleted even when nothing matched in target. Which means , data is not loaded in target yet. Problem with multithreading programs may delay loading data but they must exist one - one.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't delete from the source table (from the `using` clause) or elsewhere as part of the merge itself. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#i2081030):

> Specify the DELETE *where_clause* to clean up data in a table while populating or updating it. The only rows affected by this clause are those rows in the destination table that are updated by the merge operation.

So you can only delete from the destination table, which isn't what you want.